# Play2 "include" directive override configuration with substitution

Tags: java, configuration, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have following conf files in my play2.1.0 application

- application.conf
- override.dev.conf
- override.qa.conf
- override.prod.conf

And there is a `application.mode` property in the application.conf file which will have either one of dev/qa/prod values.

application.conf also has a line to include env/mode specific conf files as override. This is what is not working with substitution.

**Reason:**
To have the override properties in the env/mode specific conf files.

**Referred:**
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Configuration

> If an unquoted `include` at the start of a key is followed by *anything other than a single quoted string*, it is invalid and an error should be generated.
>
> *No substitutions are allowed*, and the argument may not be an unquoted string or any other kind of value.

**Tried:**

1. Able to get the substitution done for another property but not for `include` like this

   **`my.prop="override."${?application.mode}".conf"`**

   The above outputs to `override.dev.conf` if `application.mode=dev`
2. If I have something like below its not working and i suppose its what is expected as per the documentation reference.

   **`include "override."${?application.mode}".conf"`**

   Expected the above to include/override props in a file named `override.dev.conf`

**Question:**

- Should this be a future enhancement or this is what is expected out of it?
- What are the other ways to implement what I wanted?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to override the `GlobalSettings.onLoadConfig` as described in [PlayFramework 2 load different config according to current mode](http://www.codeblog.it/en/snippet/scala/2013/05/23/playframework-2-load-different-config-according-current-mode). It is done in Scala but it should be possible to do in Java as well.

It lets you overload configurations in a very nice way without the need to start the application with command line arguments, you still start the app with `play run`, `play start`, etc.

You should be able to use this method if you change your `override.qa.conf` to `override.test.conf` since `qa` is not a known mode in Play.

All shared settings in the `application.conf` and then override in the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to do something similar and the only way we got it to work was to reverse it.

In each environment we have a `main-config.conf` that has all of the configuration specific for that environment. Basically, what you are calling your `override.[env].conf`. The first line in each of those files is `includes "application.conf"` to merge in the default configuration for the application. So, `application.conf` has the general project configuration and the other files have the stuff specific to the environment.

To start your app you just tell it to use the environment-specific config file.

```
play -Dconfig.file=/path/to/main-config.conf start
```

The application will load `main-config.conf` which, in turn, includes the default `application.conf` from the project.

We actually also modify the `build` shell script (in the `/framework` directory, I believe) so it always specifies that config file parameter. That way we don't have to type that in when we're developing.