# Include an environment specific conf file with one line

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework

So I am trying to do this in the application.conf file:

```
include environments/${server_env}.conf
```

but obviously it doesn't work as I read that "include should be followed by a non-quoted sequence of chars". Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#includes) is very specific about this:

> Value concatenation is NOT performed on the "argument" to include or url() etc. The argument must be a single quoted string. No substitutions are allowed, and the argument may not be an unquoted string or any other kind of value.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157231/play2-include-directive-override-configuration-with-substitution) for some alternatives.